# How to set the height of a recycler view in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set the height of the recycler view, but I have always the toolbar which is trasparent over the recycler view, and I'm trying to use the `android:paddington` it doesn't help a lot

here is how it looks now

[image: Screenshot]

So how it would be possible to fix that

Here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my toolbar xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: *android:paddington* Really ? Paddington ? I'm sorry to say the one who told you to use the _paddington_ property was actually trolling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **RelativeLayout** as parent layout, change it to vertical **LinearLayout** and your views will not overlap.

[image: Difference between Linear and Relative layout]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make some changes in layout relation like as bellow code:

android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" on my_recycler_view

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```